# Creating a function that can be invoked a given number of times and no more

Tags: javascript, function, higher-order-functions

Say you have a function that you can input an alert with "hey" and you want to allow that to happen a given number of times — say 2, or 3, or whatever you want — and then after that given number alerts the same amount of times a negative or "no more" type string.

So you want your function to invoke n number of times

```
var hey = funky(function(){alert("hey")},3);

hey();
```

How do you do that?

Comment: with a loop? Do I understand the question?

Comment: Or do you mean a function that has one effect the first n times it is invoked, but a different (or no) effect after that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`funky` needs to be a "higher-order" function which "transforms" your input function into one that runs only the first `n` times:

```
 function funky(fn, n) {
     return function() {
         return n-- > 0 ? fn.apply(this, arguments) : "No more";
     };
 }
```

Here, we've used `fn.apply` to allow the user to pass through `this` and arguments to the returned function, so you can do things like:

```
var hey = funky(function(name){ alert("hey " + name); }, 3);

hey("Bob"); // alert("hey Bob")
hey("Joe"); // alert("hey Joe")
hey("Sam"); // alert("hey Sam")
hey("Don"); // no alert, returns "No more"
```

Passing arguments to the derived function is useful enough, but in what situations does it matter that it would honor `this`? Obviously only if objects and their methods are involved. Consider:

```
// Constructor to create new MyAlerter object, with magic number
var MyAlerter = function(magic) {
    this.magic = magic;
}

// Method on MyAlerter to put up alert with magic number
MyAlerter.prototype.alert = function(name) {
  alert("hey " + name + ", your magic number is " + this.magic);
};
```

Now we want to make a function/method `hey`, based on the `alert` method, which restricts the number of calls to three. We already have the `funky` function to do that:

```
MyAlerter.prototype.hey = funky(MyAlerter.prototype.alert, 3);
```

Now we can do this:

```
var alerter = new MyAlerter(42);

alerter.hey("Bob"); // alert("hey Bob, your magic number is 42")
alerter.hey("Joe"); // alert("hey Joe, your magic number is 42")
alerter.hey("Sam"); // alert("hey Sam, your magic number is 42")
alerter.hey("Don"); // no alert, returns "No more"
```

By passing through the `this` with which `hey` is called to the underlying function `alert`, as accomplished by the `fn.apply` inside `funky`, `alert` receives the proper `this` and is able to access the magic number.

Comment: Using *apply* is pointless as there's no mechanism to set *this* in the call or provide arguments, so the function will always be called without setting its *this* (and hence it will either default to the global object or remain *undefined* in strict mode). It does hint at useful enhancements though. ;-)

Comment: There is clearly a means to provide arguments, as in `hey("Bob")`. `this` could be passed easily enough via `hey.call(obj, "Bob")`, but I will construct a more real-world scenario.

Comment: Cool, you added the enhancements. Can't upvote you again though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You mean like a for loop?

```
function funky (fn, n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
        fn();
    }
}

funky(function () {
    alert('ABC');
}, 3);
```

If you don't want it to run immediately then you could do:

```
function funky(fn, n) {
    this.run = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
            fn();
        }
    }
}

var hey = new funky(function() {
    alert('ABC');
}, 3);

hey.run();//Alerts ABC 3 times
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1m6r46yo/)

Also:

```
function funky(fn, n) {
    return function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
            fn();
        }
    }
}

var hey = funky(function() {
    alert('ABC');
}, 3);

hey();//Alerts ABC 3 times
```